# XCode: How to join two lines?

Tags: xcode

Say I have this:

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = 
CGColorGetColorSpace(col.CGColor);
```

Is there a hotkey in XCode that lets me join these two lines together into:

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorGetColorSpace(col.CGColor);
```

?

Answer (score 14):

Simplest method I have found: Position your cursor at the end of a line, then CTRL-SHIFT-RIGHT CTRL-SHIFT-LEFT SPACE.

There is no such function like the "J" command in VI.

Comment: This is an outdated answer. That might have been true 11 years ago, but in 2023 XCode has a ^J command.

Answer (score 8):

Old question but I was looking for a way today, and ended up adding:

```
<key>JoinLines</key>
<dict>
    <key>Join Current Line</key>
    <string>moveDown:, moveToBeginningOfText:, deleteToBeginningOfLine:, deleteBackward:</string>
</dict>
```

In file:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist
```

(to be edited with sudo)

Then restart XCode, go to preferences -> Key Bindings, and assign some shortcut to "Join Current Line". Seems to work!

Comment: You're a genius! I can't believe someone figured this out 8 years later.

Comment: Actually, ^J is "join paragraphs". If you do custom bindings, they need to be re-added with each update of XCode. Multiple keys can be defined in a <dict></dict> section. I'd add 'moveToEndOfText' at the end to be able to keep hitting key and joining lines. And probably a variant (w/modifier key) to insert "," at each join. I found this video that details it more. Related resources I found (including list of XCode 'commands'): luisobo.wordpress.com, github.com/luisobo/Xcode-RuntimeHeaders/blob/master/HexFiend/…, youtube.com/watch?v=Gw7V2COqiJc,

Comment: Alternative to hacking a 'comma join' command: Though found in the runtime headers XCode has an `insertText:` command. Not hard to do it manually. Let's say you want combine vertical list of var names into horizontal list separated w/commas (e.g. [ var1, var2, var3 ...]): `opt + ` *drag vertically* from var1...varN, then `cmd + right arrow` makes flashing cursor move to after last char of each line, even if lines have diff lengths (Bravo!). Then type a comma `,`. Whalla! now each line will have a comma at the end. Then go to top line & keep hitting ^J to join them. – 
clearlight
 5 mins ago

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 13.2 added CTRL-J [Join paragraphs (Deletions)].

[image: XCode Key bindings]

Answer (score 2):

There's at least one extension for Xcode Source Editor that provides "Join Lines" command, available in AppStore: TextPlus. After installing and activating the extension, you can assign any shortcut to the corresponding "Join Lines" menu via Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings.